# I can't connect my server with Mysql/Mariadb remotly

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, centos7, firewall

Problem to connect with mysql remotely

Hello, I don't know if the right stack is this, if don't please tell me which could be the right.

I have two virtual machines and I have a principal server A, then with a machine B I connect with A with "mysql - h x.x.x.x user - p" and all functions, but when I want that my partner in other state can connect with A he get an error. We have tried everything, even we stop the firewall.

All this happens in Centos 7, I think that maybe this are thinks about servers, but I don't know any about that.

If it is necessary more information just tell me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked selinux and the database GRANTs?

Comment: is your database listening on external IP-Address?

Comment: Yes I have given the right GRANTs to the users.

Comment: And I don't know how to do that of listening on external IP-Address, I just did this with my firewall "sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent". I don't know so much about networks.

Comment: And I just added to my config file "server_id=1" and "log_bin=binlogs_mysql".

Comment: From another state, then their IP would be needed to be able to remotely connect from that host. If the other person is unsure what the IP may be, they can use [myip.com](https://www.myip.com/), or a similar site, to get the value. This IP would likely NOT be the same as the PC in their home, if they are using a router/modem unless they are using a known static IP. I've done a similar config, but it's been awhile.